# geopy returns latitude and longitude for None

Tags: geopy

I'm trying to set my address to None by geopy returns a value for latitude and longitude.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()
addr = None
location = geolocator.geocode(addr)
print location.latitude, location.longitude
```

Result

```
44.933143 7.540121
```

Comment: Why would you do that? The [docs](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy.geocoders.Nominatim.geocode) explicitly say that the allowed types for the `query` param are dict or str. `None` is neither of that.

Comment: The `None` gets interpreted as string `"None"`, for which you're seeing the result.